# Adding Contextual Menu Items iOS Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

Is there any programmatic way to add an additional menu item into iOS browser's (Safari/Chrome) context menu for text selection?
Now I have 3 items: Copy, Define, Speak.

I need to add a button (context item) which will do HTTP POST with selected text. I am new in iOS and I am looking for manual to start with.

Comment: You should really elaborate and include any research you have done.

Comment: yes, is possible but it can be done in different ways and you should explain a little bit more what you tried to do.

Comment: I need to add a button (context item) which will do HTTP POST with selected text. I am new in iOS and I am looking for manual to start with.

Comment: You can't add contextual menus to apps you don't have access to. The system Safari is Apples. They gave us WKWebView SFSafariControllerView and UIWebView. You can add these to your app. Not someone else's

Comment: You suppress the system contextual menu on safari and provide a custom one

Comment: IgnazioC, can I do it without jailbreak?